# Query within another query to count amount of items from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here's a summarized database schema:

```
Table: posts 
Columns: id, contents

Table: comments
Columns: id, post_id, contents
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
SELECT *, (select number of comments from comments table 
           where post_id = id of posts table) AS num_comments 
FROM posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,CASE WHEN commentScount IS NULL 
            THEN 0 ELSE commentScount END AS commentScount
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id ,COUNT(*)/0.5 commentScount 
             FROM comments GROUP BY post_id) AS c
ON p.id = c.post_id;
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775e6/3)

Comment: I forgot to add something to the post. I need to divide the commentScount with a number, like let's say 0.5. How do I do that?